# Target multiple select and remove for dropdown in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have total 6 dropdowns in my excel. In those, I need multiple select and remove only for specific dropdowns. I have used the VBA code from the internet. When I use that code, the multiple select and remove is getting applied to all the dropdowns but I want it to only get applied to specific target dropdowns. How do I set target dropdown for multiple select and Remove with the help of VBA code?

I have the following columns (Category and Region) in my excel.I want to restrict selection to only one where user can only select one category either A, B, C but can have multiple selection and removal for Region column.

```
CATEGORY REGION    
A         USA    
B         MEX    
C         GER
```

This is the VBA code which I have used.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim xValue1 As String
    Dim xValue2 As String
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If xRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, xRng) Is Nothing Then
        xValue2 = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        xValue1 = Target.Value
        Target.Value = xValue2
        If xValue1 <> "" Then
            If xValue2 <> "" Then
                If InStr(1, xValue1, xValue2 & ",") > 0 Then
                    xValue1 = Replace(xValue1, xValue2 & ", ", "") ' If it's in the middle with comma
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If InStr(1, xValue1, ", " & xValue2) > 0 Then
                    xValue1 = Replace(xValue1, ", " & xValue2, "") ' If it's at the end with a comma in front of it
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                If xValue1 = xValue2 Then        ' If it is the only item in string
                    xValue1 = ""
                    Target.Value = xValue1
                    GoTo jumpOut
                End If
                Target.Value = xValue1 & ", " & xValue2
            End If
jumpOut:
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `Set xRng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)` set it to the range where your DropDownBoxes are. Eg if they are in A1 and C15 use  `Set xRng = Me.Range("A1,C15").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)`

Comment: Even after adding target, it's getting applied to all the dropdowns.The code is not working

Comment: @Pᴇʜ `Set xRng = Me.Range("B2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)` I have used this as I want only for regions multiple select but unfortunately category is also showing multiple select

Comment: Well my bad just use `Me.Range("A1,C15")` without `SpecialCells`.

Comment: Sorry, It worked now. I made a mistake while doing. Thank you so much @Pᴇʜ